# Porcentagem javascript ou php

Tags: php

Tenho esses 3 botoes, um valor de custo - margem de lucro - valor de venda. 
Preciso que ele calcule o valor de venda automatico, coloco o valor do custo coloco a margem de lucro ele mostra dentro do campo valor de venda automaticamente, alguem sabe dizer como posso fazer isso?

tentei fazer com

```
function porcentagem_xn ( $porcentagem, $total ) {
    return ( $porcentagem / 100 ) * $total;
}
```

porem não consigo chamar no campo que eu quero e nem que apareça o resultado automaticamente no campo valor de venda

```
<div type="text" class="col-lg-2 ">
    <label >Valor de Custo:</label>
    <input type="int" name="txt_custo" class="form-control number_format">          
</div> 
<div type="text" class="col-lg-1  ">
    <label >Margem(%):</label>
    <input type="int" name="txt_margem" class="form-control"  > 
</div> 
<div type="text" class="col-lg-2  ">
    <label >Valor de Venda:</label>
    <input type="int"  name="txt_venda" class="form-control">           
</div>
```

Comment: Os tipos dos inputs não podem ser a causa do problema? Não existe `input type=int` mas sim `input type=number`. Fora isso, não sei que o que pode ser.

Answer (score -1):

Acho que isso deve servir para calcular.

```
$('.valor').blur(function(){ // uso a classe valor para chamar o blur por mais de um campo
    var custo = $("input[name=txt_custo]").val() || 0;
    var margem = $("input[name=txt_margem]").val() || 0;
    var valor_total = 0;

    valor_total = ( margem / 100 ) * custo ;
    $("#txt_venda").val(parseFloat(valor_total));
});
```

Comment: onBlur="$('.valor')" , isso?

Answer (score -1):

Para calcular o Lucro você pode fazer dessa forma.
Na chamada desta função passe o valor de Custo e o percentual de lucro desejado.

```
function calculaValor(valorCusto, percentualLucro){
   return (valorCusto + (valorCusto * (percentualLucro / 100)));
}
```